# Automatic click html button

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I am making a chrome extension and I am stuck with javascript and pressing button on page. I have site with form like this on web(isn't mine so i can't edit it):

```
 <input class="button" name="accept" type="submit" value=LoggIn">
```

And now I automatically open page with username and password filled but now I want that button will be clicked automatically.

### Thx for help!

Edit:

I have code of script:

```
var tabID = 1;
chrome.tabs.create({index:tabID,url:"https://monostudby4frd.hisf.no:8001/",active:false,pinned:true},
function(tab) {
    tabID = tab.id;
}); 

sleep(3000);
chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, {code:clickButton()});
sleep(3000);

chrome.tabs.getSelected(null, function(tab) {
    chrome.tabs.remove(tabID);
});



function sleep(ms) {
    var dt = new Date();
    dt.setTime(dt.getTime() + ms);
    while (new Date().getTime() < dt.getTime());
}

function clickButton() {
    document.getElementById("accept").click();
}
```

And debugger says:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'click' of null
```

Comment: With a chrome extension you can edit html on web pages whether it's yours or not.

Comment: But I need to edit page?

Answer (score 1):

Button inputs are simple: `inputElem.click()`

Comment: Hey, it will be something like this?
 `chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, {code:document.getElementById("accept").click()}); `

Answer (score 0):

You can use jquery to trigger a click event.

You shouldn't really be auto-submitting a form, though.

```
<form onsubmit='doSomething();'>
    <input id="submitButton" class="button" name="accept" type="submit" value="LoggIn">
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function doSomething() {

        console.log("Clicked!");

    }

    $("#submitButton").trigger('click');
</script>
```